# Как остановить handler?

Tags: java, android

Имеется handler.

```
 h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {

    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg){
            switch(msg.what){
            case 1:
                // что то выполняется
                break;
            case 2:
                // что то выполняется
                break;
            case 3:
                // что то выполняется
                break;
            }

            }}
```

Отправляю ему сообщения вот так:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                    try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    h.sendEmptyMessage(i);
                }}
        });
        t.start();
```

в каждом `case` проверяется условие, и в случае если оно правдиво хотелось бы иметь возможность остановить все последующие действия.
К примеру в `case 1` условие истинно, соответственно `case 2` и все последующие не будут выполнены.

Простите если я выразился как то некорректно, объясняю так как понимаю на данном этапе сам.

Comment: Вы хотите остановить поток? - заведите volatile переменную-флаг, ставьте его в хэндлере, проверяйте его в потоке. Или не хотите выполнять действия? - тоже добавьте флаг, проверяйте его перед switch... Можно обе проверки сделать и флаг один и тот же использовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ основан на ответе @Yura Ivanov
Добавил переменную `int stop_handler = 1;`
Проверяю перед `switch`

```
h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {

            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg){
                if(stop_handler != 0) {
                    switch(msg.what){
                        case 1:
                            // при положительном результате проверки
                            // выполняется присваивание значения 0 переменной
                            // и соответственно дальнейшие действия не выполняются
                             stop_handler = 0;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            // при положительном результате проверки
                            // выполняется присваивание значения 0 переменной
                            // и соответственно дальнейшие действия не выполняются
                             stop_handler = 0;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            // при положительном результате проверки
                            // выполняется присваивание значения 0 переменной
                            // и соответственно дальнейшие действия не выполняются
                             stop_handler = 0;
                            break;
                    }

                }}};
```